# Zend Framework Default Error

Tags: zend-framework, error-handling, zend-form

How can i get rid of Zend default error not to show "Value is required and can't be empty"

Thanks

I'm using this method:

```
$this->addElement(
    'text',
    'testname',
     array(
        'label' => 'User Name',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array(
          'StringTrim'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: You should pass a valid value to whatever method/function throws that error !

Comment: it could be done by using `$element->setRequired(false);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to change the actual message text then use something like this:

```
$field = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('field');
$field ->setRequired(TRUE)
    ->addValidator(
        'NotEmpty', //validator name
        FALSE, //do not break on failure
        array(messages' => array(
                'isEmpty' => 'INSERT CUSTOM MESSAGE HERE' 
            )
        )
    )
```

Here you change the 'isEmpty' message of the NotEmpty validator.

Or if you defined the element differently.

```
$element = $this->getElement('text');
$element->addValidator('NotEmpty', //validator name
    FALSE, //do not break on failure
    array(messages' => array(
            'isEmpty' => 'INSERT CUSTOM MESSAGE HERE' 
        )
    )
 )
```

Comment: I'm using this method:

$this->addElement('text', 'testname', array(

'label' => 'User Name',
  'required' => true,

  'filters'  => array('StringTrim')));

Comment: 'required' => true is simply a proxy to the NotEmpty validator, if you need to change the message you recieve on failure, then do something like I have done above.

Answer (score 2):

In Zend_Form this is the default error message of the default validator 'Empty'. 
To remove this validator, on the element add the removeValidator() function with 'empty' as the parameter:

```
$element->removeValidator('Empty');
```

This is assuming you have made a form in Zend_Form, that you have POSTed an empty value and are trying to validate it?

Going forward, please provide more information.

Comment: or just $element->setRequired(FALSE) ?

Comment: i'm using this way: I'm using this method:

$this->addElement('text', 'testname', array(

'label' => 'User Name',
  'required' => true,

  'filters'  => array('StringTrim')));

Comment: no thats going to make the entire message go away..i just want the string to go away

Comment: You want the error, but not that error message? see @Adam Pointer's answer